What's the maximum span for 2x4 floor joists?
I want to build a wood-over-concrete joist floor in my basement using galvanized adjustable joist supports (from Klevaklip), the clips get attached to the concrete.  The clips are needed to keep the joists above the concrete and any occasional water draining level.  It is an older 1950s home and the basement ceiling height is limited, so it will require 2x4 joists with 17/32 OSB flooring panels.
The concrete is sloped so occasional water leakage through the cinder block walls run toward a central drain.  It only happens during heavy rain, 2 or 3 times a year and it dries pretty quickly. And the water is always negligible at 1/8 of an inch.
I plan to use 16" spacing on center for the wood joists.  How far apart should the clips be to safely support 2x4 joists?

Only comment, Do Not use OSB.   OSB and any water or moisture = problems.

Thanks.  But there will be a gap between between the lumber floor and the basement walls.  The water only drips in during heavy storms and will never touch the OSB.  The water will drain under the raised lumber joists

"Moisture" includes more than just running water; the presence of water creates high humidity in the enclosed space which will cause mold in the OSB.

OSB is fine with precautions. It's built with exterior-grade adhesive and doesn't have problems unless it gets soaked, which it shouldn't from what you describe. In cases like this (and yard sheds), I use treated framing and overlay house wrap or poly sheeting before installing the subfloor.

English protip: 17/32 reads as "seventeen thirty-seconds", so 17/32nd reads as "seventeen thirty-seconds-nd". (You knew that in third grade. Musta forgot. :) )

Wonder if the 17 is a typo.  Just seems weird to have an extra 1/32 size over 1/2 inch

@crip659 - 1/2 inch is 16/32. 17/32 is one 1/32 less than 18/32 which is the nominal size for 9/16 sheet material.

@MichaelKaras   Most wood is sold by nominal size.  17/32 seems like an actual measured size, so it seems odd to me.

Technically 9/16 would be the nominal size, and 17/32 is the actual (though I've never seen either of those in stores or lumber yards).

I'm thinking of including squirrel cage fans to blow air under the platform to keep it dry.   Thanks for all the great tips.
